# HUKD API - getJSON Rest call

Tags: jquery, json, api, rest

I'm new to JSON and APIs (everything like that).

I am trying to test out the API over at Hot UK Deals (http://www.hotukdeals.com/rest-api), for a future development.

I have an API key and would like to retrieve data from the hot vouchers.

http://api.hotukdeals.com/rest_api/v2/?key=xxxxxxxxxxx&order=hot&forum=vouchers&results_per_page=5

Now I want to just select one and display it. I can't even do that, I'm not sure if it's something that I'm doing wrong or what.

Now here's my JS code:

```
$.getJSON('http://api.hotukdeals.com/rest_api/v2/?key=xxxxxxxxx&order=hot&forum=vouchers&results_per_page=5&output=json',function(hot){  

    $('div#data').html(hot.title)



        });//end JSON
```

Now before someone says, that I haven't tried; I have! I have tried different ways to get the title of a deal. But I can't get any output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The API only supports JSON ans XML, not JSONP. This means that you cannot use javascript in order to consume it due to the [same origin policy restriction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Browsers forbid from sending AJAX to different domains. Basically there are two workarounds for this restriction:

1. [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) (which unfortunately requires the server to support it, which doesn't seem to be the case for the API you are trying to consume)
2. Use a server side script on your domain that will act as a bridge and send the AJAX request to your script.

Comment: But I'm using JSON not JSONP. Arnt I? $.getJSON How would you develop with this api then? What method of calling and retrieving? - Thanks :)

Comment: @hart1994m yes you are using $.getJSON but the url that you pass to this function doesn't belong to your domain. That's the problem. So as I said there are 2 possibilities. You may forget about the first as the server doesn't support it. The second consists into writing a server side script on your domain. Depending on the server side language you are using this will vary of course. But you cannot consume this API using javascript directly.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I am trying now with their php proxy. I don't fully understand it. http://www.hotukdeals.com/test-widget.php.txt Do you? Thanks :)